# Visual Studio 2017 Extensions and Updates GZip error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Online fails to search the Visual Studio Marketplace with the following error:

> The magic number in GZip header is not correct.  Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream.

Updates for Visual Studio itself work fine and I've updated several times, however this error occurs for each version of 2017 I've installed.

I am running Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 15.3.5

I have VS2015 on the same machine and do not get this error.

Comment: I am also having this error. Looks like theres an issue in 15.3.4 thats being fixed in 15.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved in version 15.4.1, no special configuration or settings changes required.